# Maven Profile not getting activated

Tags: java, maven-3, maven-profiles

**Tools :**

Maven 3

**Issue :**

I have a parent `pom.xml` which has a profile setting as below -

```
<profile>
      <id>Junits-run</id>
      <activation>
        <file>
          <exists>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</exists>
        </file>
      </activation>
```

In my child project , I do have packages inside `src/test/java` folder like `src/test/java/org/example.`

But still this profile is not getting activated.

Can anybody please advice why is this happening ?

Comment: Try command `mvn package -PJunits-run`

Comment: That is running. But I want to get this profile included when the test files exists in /src/test/java